# Creating a card game on python by using Classes and Functions - EDIT

Tags: python, class, playing-cards

I'm learning Python programming and i'm trying to make a working popular card  game.

I'm starting from the skeleton, so I wrote some code to create the deck and to deal cards and shuffle the deck.
Now I want to create 2 players that "have" a hand, in which they can keep a maximum of 3 cards, and can "draw" cards from the deck.
I thought about a player class, in which are defined the name and hand attributes for each different player, but when i tried to draw cards with player1 it also added the cards to player2's hand. How can i change it so it adds the cards to a a player and only to him, removing them from the deck? What is wrong with my solution?

Output:

```
['10 di Denari', '1 di Coppe']
['10 di Denari', '1 di Coppe', '6 di Denari', '5 di Denari']
```

Can you help me understanding how to get it to work?

EDIT: Yeah i pasted the wrong code, here is the one i need help in:

```
import random
semi = ['Bastoni','Spade','Coppe','Denari']
numeri = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
mazzo = []

for element in numeri:
    for seme in semi:
        carta = str(element) + ' di ' + seme
        mazzo.append(carta)
Rimanenti = len(mazzo)
def mischia():
    random.shuffle(mazzo)
class Giocatore:
    nome = None
    mano = []
    tola = []
    def __init__(self,nome):
        self.nome=nome

    def draw(q):
        for n in range(0, q):
            pesco = random.choice(mazzo)
             Giocatore.mano.append(pesco)
            mazzo.remove(pesco)

    def turno():
        Giocatore.draw('Toni',1)
        Giocatore.draw('Piero',1)
    def inizio():
        Giocatore.draw('Toni', 3)
        Giocatore.draw('Piero', 3)


class Piero(Giocatore):
    nome = 'Piero'

class Toni(Giocatore):
    nome = 'Toni'


Toni.draw(2)
print(Toni.mano)
Piero.draw(2)
print(Piero.mano)
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Thank you all for your answers! Now I have a better understanding of the whole thing, I'm rewriting it differently!

Comment: show us what you tried in the player class and someone can tell you why it was doing what it was doing. Basically right now you are just asking people to write a big portion of the code for you and don't exactly have a question

Comment: The hand of cards for each player is not tied to an instance but the class itself, as you have it currently defined. It might be better to use a single `Player` class, where `Piero` and `Toni` are instances. Their hands would be instance variables, `self.mano`

Comment: It might even be better to use a `set` for the cards in the deck. This way, when you draw a card, you could use `deck = set(<your_cards>); draw = deck.pop(random.choice(deck))`. The `pop` operation removes the card from the deck while simultaneously returning that value to you

Comment: Though I'd recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) on classes, because as it sits, your functions will raise `TypeError`s for too many positional arguments (`self` is automatically passed in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you are misunderstanding the difference between class variables and instance variables. I'll use a simple example:

```py
class Player():
    hand = [] # hand is a class variable, as it is not tied to an instance

p1 = Player() # p1 is an instance of Player
p2 = Player() # p2 is a separate instance of Player()
```

Now, if I add something to the hand of `p1`:

```py
p1.hand.append(1)

p2.hand
# [1]
```

This is because I have defined `hand` at the *class* level, and so both `p1.hand` and `p2.hand` are *really* `Player.hand`. To change this, you will want `hand` to be attached to an instance, using `self.hand` and the `__init__` dunder method, which acts like a constructor for class instances.

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self): # self is always passed as the first argument
        self.hand = []

p1 = Player() 
p2 = Player()
```

Now, `p1.hand` is a completely different object than `p2.hand` because they were created through each call to `__init__`. Now if I add something to `p1.hand`:

```py
p1.hand.append(1)
p1.hand
# [1]
p2.hand
# []
```

They aren't both modified. Now, to touch on class functions. By default, functions in classes are instance level, which means that `self`, or the class *instance*, will be implicitly passed as the first argument. If you don't have a placeholder for `self`, you will get errors:

```py
class A():
    def a():
        print("did something")

inst = A()
a.a()
# TypeError: a() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

# To fix this
class A():
    def a(self):
        print("did something")

inst = A()
a.a()
# did something
```

### The Program

Fortunately, you've identified what you need for this program to function properly, two players, a deck of cards, and a mechanism to take turns. Because you are using `random.choice` to pick cards, I'd argue that you don't actually need a function to shuffle the deck. You can get the card by choosing a random card as you've done before:

```py
semi = ['Bastoni','Spade','Coppe','Denari']
numeri = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
mazzo = ['%d di %s' % (element, seme) for seme in semi for element in numeri]
```

To draw a card, you can use the following:

```py
# Use random.choice as you've done before
idx = random.coice(mazzo)
mazzo.remove(drawn_card)
```

The class method `remove` will remove a value from the list. Paired with your `class.hand` approach:

```py
Toni = Player()

Toni.hand.append(drawn_card)
```

Or, as a method in the `Player` class:

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self):
        # Need to convert set to list to choose
        drawn_card = random.choice(mazzo)
        mazzo.remove(drawn_card)
        self.hand.append(drawn_card)
        print(self.hand) # If you want to see the hand

toni = Player()

toni.draw()
# ['8 di Spade']
```

Though you could view that as a bit verbose. If you wanted to keep your shuffle method, then you could shuffle the deck every time and use `pop` to grab a random card as @ibonyun suggested

Answer (score 0):

You're using classes incorrectly. Making a Player class is like defining playerhood, which is the *idea* of what it is to be a player of a card game. You cannot play a card game with only the *idea* of a player; you need actual players which exemplify playerhood. In programming terms, players will **instantiate** the Player class.

You're trying to play the game with the class itself, not instances of the class.  You need to instantiate `Giocatore` twice (once for each player) and play with the instances. To instantiate you need to do something like this:

```
player1 = Giocatore('Pietro')
player2 = Giocatore('Toni')
```

At the bottom you've subclassed `Giocatore` with new classes named after the players.  Unless each player has different abilities (ie attributes and/or methods) this is unnecessary.  And it is not the same thing as instantiating `Giocatore`.

> when i tried to draw cards with player1 it also added the cards to player2's hand.... How can i change it so it adds the cards to a a player and only to him, removing them from the deck? What is wrong with my solution?

There's 2 reasons.  First, you're playing with the class itself, as I described above.  But even if you weren't doing that, there's an additional problem which is that you've made the hand `mano` a *class* attribute instead of an *instance* attribute. That means that all instances will share that attribute; therefore all players will share the exact same hand. In the `draw` method, instead of `Giocatore.mano.append(pesco)` it should be `self.mano.append(pesco)`.  That way you're putting the new card only in that player's hand, not a hand that is collectively shared by all players.

To make the hand an instance attribute, you should be defining it inside `__init__`.  That method should look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, nome):
    self.nome = nome
    self.mano = []
```

Here `self` refers to the instance.

As for removing cards from the deck, if you've already randomized them at the beginning using `random.shuffle`, there's no need to use `random.choice` when drawing a new card.  I'd recommend just popping one off the list, like this:

```
def draw(self, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        self.mano.append(mazzo.pop())
```